# Button/link to show random post from specific label in blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger, blogspot

I need help with my blog built with Googles blogger CMS: https://funatonce.blogspot.com

I am currently using the below script to generate/show random post, this script returns random post from the entire post entries. I want a similar button to show posts from specific category/labels or even mix category/labels.

I have over 5000 posts & 50+ categories/labels on my blog, thats why it will be very useful feature for my visitors.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function showLucky(root){
    var feed = root.feed;
    var entries = feed.entry || [];
    var entry = feed.entry[0];
      for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; ++j) {
       if (entry.link[j].rel == "alternate") {
       window.location = entry.link[j].href;
       }
      }
   }

function fetchLuck(luck){
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = '/feeds/posts/summary?start-index='+luck+'&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=showLucky';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
   }
function readLucky(root){
    var feed = root.feed;
    var total = parseInt(feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,10);
    var luckyNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*total);
    luckyNumber++;
    fetchLuck(luckyNumber);
    }
function feelingLucky(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '/feeds/posts/summary?max-results=0&alt=json-in-script&callback=readLucky';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
//]]>
</script>

<a href="#random" onclick="feelingLucky()" title="Random Post">Feeling Lucky?</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get posts by label add `/-/LabelName` to script src like the following

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function showLucky(root){
    var feed = root.feed;
    var entries = feed.entry || [];
    var entry = feed.entry[0];
      for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; ++j) {
       if (entry.link[j].rel == "alternate") {
       window.location = entry.link[j].href;
       }
      }
   }

function fetchLuck(luck){
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = '/feeds/posts/summary/-/LabelName?start-index='+luck+'&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=showLucky';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
   }
function readLucky(root){
    var feed = root.feed;
    var total = parseInt(feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,10);
    var luckyNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*total);
    luckyNumber++;
    fetchLuck(luckyNumber);
    }
function feelingLucky(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '/feeds/posts/summary/-/LabelName?max-results=0&alt=json-in-script&callback=readLucky';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Bassam, could you please help me with this. I want to use multiple random buttons on the website, for eg. If I want to use 15 buttons do I have to add this script 15 different times? How can I combine the script to use it for multiple buttons.

I created a .js file and used it as a reference, but its not working

<script src='http://yourjavascript.com/61446123186/random.js' type='text/javascript'/>

Comment: Ok, There is a better way. Open a new question to help other users, I will be there : )